# How to avoid using multiple IF/THEN statements in Excel when working with multiple statements that use it?

Tags: excel

Example -  I have pseudo code that looks something like the following

```
if (A1 is even)
{
    B = X + 7
    C = B + 8
    ...
    Z = 10
}
else
{
    B = N + 11
    C = 6 + B
    ...
    Z = 16
}
```

I am converting the code above to Excel form. 
Variables B, C, ... Z will become individual Excel cells, and for example variable B will end up in B1, C in C1, etc.

For each of them I can specify `IF (A1 is even) {do this}, else {do that}` for formulas B through Z.  But this way I will be repeating the IF/ELSE condition for every cell.  That is "code duplication" and I want to avoid it.

Is there a way to specify `IF/ELSE` once, or use some other method to avoid cluttering my Excel cells with the same `IF (A1 is even) (X) ELSE (Y)`?

Comment: Add extra cells.

Comment: add extra cells where ..?   are you talking about output cells?  or input ones?

Comment: Are you talking about a formula or vba?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're doing, but if you want intermediate values in Excel formulas I'm not aware of another way to do it besides breaking it into smaller formulas in neighboring cells in your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Scott: If there is pure-Excel way of doing it, it's simpler so I'd prefer that.  But because of things like this, I am considering going to vba, as it seems more powerful  In this question I have the even/odd blocks.  But i also have multiple If/else blocks in my further code, where each block has 10 or so formulas...

Comment: @Casey, I do want to show intermediate values.  But in my case even though they are intermediate, they are of interest and are consumable.  I want to show the result for i.e. B in cell B1, and have it use a different formula based on whether `A1` was even or odd.  In my case I have many cells that will have to use this logic, and not just one.  I want to avoid duplicating the `If Even/Odd` for every cell from B to Z in my example

Comment: You can use intermediate cells and hide the columns or rows you are calculating in, but which you don't want to show. And you can unprotect input cells, protect result cells. Then protecting the sheet makes the day.

Comment: You can create a loop that goes through each cell in a range...is that what you mean? You can do, say `For each cel in Range("A1:Z10") // If cel.Value mod 2 = 0 Then // do something for EVEN // Else // Do something for odd // next cel`...?

Comment: Right, so you add a column and fill it with `=AND(ISEVEN(E2), ISEVEN(E3))` or whatever.

Comment: you can create section in your excel sheet Say column ZA where all the even values are calculated, and column ZB where all odd values are calculated,  then do something like INDEX(ZA:ZB,0,if(ISEVEN(A1),1,2)).  zero returns the whole column, so you can change it to row number or some other reference means to suit your needs for pulling the info/

Comment: mmm I like the intermediary cell suggestion I think.  I am thinking of having two columns somewhere that are hidden, one for odd formula results, one for even ones.  And then I have a simple picker for my "to be seen" cells, where I can use IF/THEN many times without cluttering my main formulas with IF/ELSE.  Still a little bit ugly though either way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

[image: SO45552254 example]

where the formula in B4:

```
=IF(ISEVEN($A$1),B1,B2)
```

is copied across to suit.